# Notation for a sequence as a set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology

The natural notation for a sequence $x:\mathbb{N}\to X$ in a set $X$ is $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. The problem with this notation is that, assuming that we already defined or familiar with bounded/closed/compact/... set, we need to define bounded/closed/compact/... sequence as a sequence whose range $$\label{range}\tag{1}\{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}:=\{x(n) \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$ is bounded/closed/compact/...

Also we can not use sets operation such as $\{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$, union, intersection, etc., if a sequence is a function.

I guess, this is why some books write "let $\{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ be a sequence", but then there are other problems, since we cannot treat the range set as a function, order matters, and $$\{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}=\{y_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$ may hold to different sequences $x\neq y$.

My best idea is to define $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ as in \eqref{range}, to be the range of a function $x$, and not a sequence. Then allow to use it as in  "Let $\{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$" where $x$ is implicitly defined or clear from the context.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: there is no problem with the standard notation for sequences, and of course writing something like $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset X$ is wrong, and indeed I never see something like that in a serious book of mathematics. Neither heard about "closed" or "compact" sequences.

Comment: See e.g. this book: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611974997

Comment: The set notation is also common in this web-site due to the reasons I mentioned. For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937800/intersection-of-two-infinite-sequences-is-a-finite-set

Comment: @Masacroso Unfortunately, for some odd reason, many serious books use the notation $\{a_n\}$ to denote sequences.

Comment: Is this in the context of writing a textbook or learning resource or in a context where the reader already knows what it means for a sequence to be bounded/closed/compact/...? If the first, what's the problem with adding a sentence of the form "we say a sequence $(x_n)$ is *blah* if the set $\{x_n\}$ is *blah*"? Is there an adjective that applies to both sequences and sets but has inequivalent meanings when applied to the sequence $(x_n)$ and the set $\{x_n\}$?

Comment: This is in the context of writing papers and books with a consistent notation. The question is what is "blah" in your answer. For example, I use $\{p_i\}_{i\in[n]}\subseteq R^d$ to define a set of points in $ R^d$, which implies that there are no repetitions. Defining $\{p_i\}_{i\in N}$ to be a function (sequence) $f:N\to R$ that may not be bijective would yield inconsistency. To be able to use sequences with set theory (e.g. intersection, substraction and addition) while still be consistent, I decided to use the suggestion in my new answer.

Comment: ...which is "$(x_i)_{i\in N}$ in R" is a sequence , and  $\{x_i\}_{i\in N}:=\{x(i)\mid i\in N \}$ is it ranges, for set operators.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what usage you have a problem with. What is the problem with always writing "let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$"? I'm not sure what you mean by using union or intersection with sequences.

Comment: For example, I work with piecewise linear signals, so I use $x_n=\infty$ if the sequence is not defined in time $n$, and use dom(x) as the domain of the function (sequence). Merging such sequences is easy by taking the union of the range of two sequences. Taking the corresponding "union or intersection of functions" is a mess. Similarly using partitions of a signal, substraction between them and so on.

Comment: Check out this terrible notation that I try to reformulate using the above ideas: 
https://openreview.net/forum?id=pgJp7rDc_hk